# Porque a app não sai da tela branca e não dá erros?

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo um app bem básico com uma tela que simula uma cartela de Bingo.

O problema é o seguinte, quando executo o código, sem a verificação de números repetidos(pois em uma cartela de bingo não podem existir números repetidos), o programa roda tranquilamente:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Random nRand = new Random();
            ArrayList<View> btn;
            int[] sorteados = new int[25];
            View cartela = findViewById(R.id.CartelaMain); //CartelaMain é o layout principal onde estão os 25 botões e um TextView
            btn = cartela.getTouchables();
    
            for(int cont = 0;cont < btn.size();cont++){
                int numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1; //Definindo o numero randômico
                Button botao = (Button) btn.get(contA); //Instanciando o botão
                String txt1 = Integer.toString(numero); //Passando de int para String
                botao.setText(txt1); //Set texto do botao
            }
        }
```

Agora, quando eu aplico a verificação:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Random nRand = new Random();
            ArrayList<View> btn;
            int[] sorteados = new int[25];
            View cartela = findViewById(R.id.CartelaMain); //CartelaMain é o layout principal onde estão os 25 botões e um TextView
            btn = cartela.getTouchables();
    
            for (int contA = 0; contA < btn.size(); contA++) { //Este método gera os numeros randomicametne e verifica por repetição dos numeros sorteados 
                int numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
                Boolean continuar = true;
                do {
                    Boolean sair = true;
                    for (int contB = 0; contB < btn.size(); contB++) {
                        int aux = sorteados[contB];
                        if(aux == numero){
                            numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
                            continuar = !sair;
                            contB = contB - 1;
                        }
                   }
    
                } while (!continuar) ;
    
                sorteados[contA] = numero; //Armazenamento do numero no Array
                Button botao = (Button) btn.get(contA); //Instanciando o botão
                String txt1 = Integer.toString(numero); //Passando de int para String
                botao.setText(txt1); //Set texto do botão
    
            }
    
        }
```

O app simplesmente não sai da tela branca. Não há registro de erros de compilação por parte do Android Studio e eu também já debuggei umas 4 vezes.

---

Acebei encontrando a solução para a situação acima, havia um laço de loop infinito:

```
int numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
            Boolean continuar = true;
            do {
                Boolean sair = true;
                for (int contB = 0; contB < btn.size(); contB++) {
                    int aux = sorteados[contB];
                    if(aux == numero){
                        numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
                        continuar = !sair;
                        contB = contB - 1;
                    }
               }

            } while (!continuar) ;
```

O problema estava em um loop infinito do método do/while(que é totalmente desnecessário tendo em vista que o próprio for pode impedir a saída de um numero repetido) que a partir do momento em que a verificação desse positiva, dois erros aconteciam:

1º - continuar = !sair; -> Por culpa desse comando, o do/while continuava para sempre.

2º - contB = contB - 1; ->Quando declarado dessa forma, o laço criado para verificação não era efetivo. Ex:

```
for(cont = 0;cont < 5; cont++){ //Suponde que este é o terceiro ciclo cont = 3
    cont = cont - 1; //Implica que o cont vai voltar uma casa somente e não que ele vai começar do zero.
}
```

Corrigindo, o código fica assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            Random nRand = new Random();
            ArrayList<View> btn;
            int[] sorteados = new int[25];
            View cartela = findViewById(R.id.CartelaMain); //CartelaMain é o layout principal onde estão os 25 botões e um TextView
            btn = cartela.getTouchables();
    
            for (int contA = 0; contA < btn.size(); contA++) { //Este método gera os numeros randomicametne e verifica por repetição dos numeros sorteados 

                for (int contB = 0; contB < btn.size(); contB++) {
                    int aux = sorteados[contB];
                    if(aux == numero){
                        numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
                        contB = -1;
                    }
               }
    
                sorteados[contA] = numero; //Armazenamento do numero no Array
                Button botao = (Button) btn.get(contA); //Instanciando o botão
                String txt1 = Integer.toString(numero); //Passando de int para String
                botao.setText(txt1); //Set texto do botão
    
            }
    
        }
```

RESOLVIDO

Comment: Por favor, alguém poderia me ajudar nessa situação ?? Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int contA = 0; contA < btn.size(); contA++) {
        int numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        Boolean continuar = true;
        for (int contB = 0; contB < btn.size(); contB++) {
             int aux = sorteados[contB];
             if(aux == numero){
                continuar = false;
                contA -= 1;
                break;
             }
        }
        if(continuar == true){
           sorteados[contA] = numero;
           Button botao = (Button) btn.get(contA);
           String txt1 = Integer.toString(numero);
           botao.setText(txt1);
        }
    }
```

Não testei o código, mas aqui tens uma função que deve fazer o que desejas, se tiveres alguma dúvida ou não entenderes algo diz.

Como já disse, não testei o código e se tiver algum erro diz, que eu tento resolver.

Acho que este não e o melhor método para tratar disto, mas acho que ira funcionar, boa sorte!

Acho que se poderia utilizar o `ArrayUtils.contains(array, key);` - nunca utilizei mas é uma questão de experimentar :) Vou fazer aqui o código com esta solução, experimenta e depois diz se funcionou ou não.

```
for (int contA = 0; contA < btn.size(); contA++) {
        int numero = nRand.nextInt(99) + 1;
        if(ArrayUtils.contains(btn, numero);){
           sorteados[contA] = numero;
           Button botao = (Button) btn.get(contA);
           String txt1 = Integer.toString(numero);
           botao.setText(txt1);
        }else{
           contA -= 1;
        }
    }
```

Volto a repetir, que não testei nenhum destes códigos, e poderá haver alguns erros, se houver e se não conseguires resolver diz.

Comment: Eu tentei implementar a ideia, mas o Android Studio não tem esse método ArrayUtils.contains. O mais engraçado é que, o "erro" só ocorre quando eu faço ele realizar o método de repetição. Vou aguardar o seu teste. Obrigado.